# What were the main causes of the spike and drop of DRYS's stock price?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis

DryShips Inc. (DRYS) started off at $1 million per share, ballooned up to a few million per share between 2007-2008, then it declined dramatically from there. Now it's going for a few dollars. What could cause this dramatic of price change?!

Comment: What is people's obsession with this company?

Comment: @quid It's the million dollar price tag that makes people do a double-take

Comment: The company never traded for a million dollars a share.  There have been 5 reverse splits since 2016.  1:25, 1:4, 1:15, 1:8 and 1:4.  These reverse splits turned 48,000 at the beginning of 2016 shares in to 1 today.  The company is running at -800% net margin.  There's no telling why this thing still exists.  The highest price this company ever got to, ever, is about $123 ($5,928,000 illustrated historical price divided by 48,000 the equivalent number of shares of a single share today)

Comment: @quid wow that is insane! I don't know why it's still listed either or how that's even allowed to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a declining company and used as an institutional sized pump and dump with a new toxic financing every week. Look up Kalani Investments - they're behind it all.